# JPA Query find by parameter other than id

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, dao

I've got a MySQL database which contains a table named `User`. It has two columns. One is named `ID`, the other is `EMAIL`. It has more columns but that is irrelevant to the question.

In my DAO-object, I'd like to create a method named `findByEmail`. It currently looks like this:

```
@Override
public User findByEmail(String email) {
    Object obj = em.createQuery("FROM User WHERE EMAIL LIKE :email").setParameter("email", email).getSingleResult();
    User user = (User)obj;
    return user;        
}
```

This gives a nullpointer-exception. My guess is, my query is wrong. Can anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: usually a JPA query will be like "select r FROM User r WHERE r.EMAIL = :email" since you cant put like in Email

Comment: That is invalid JPQL (check the spec for the "SELECT" part). Clearly you may be using some (Hibernate) implementation-specific but then that ought to be mentioned in any question if you are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the MySQL-server was configured to block all remote connections. It now works (with the JPA query supplied by vels4j, `select r FROM User r WHERE r.EMAIL = :email`)

Answer (score 0):

as you said, you can do it that way. But if you wanted to follow a closer SQL approach, you might as well use

```
    @Override
public User findByEmail(String email) {
    Object obj = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL = " + email).getSingleResult();
    User user = (User)obj;
    return user;        
}
```

Also if you want to shorten the code you could declare and cast the user in the same line you execute the query, like so:

```
User user = (User) em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE EMAIL = " + email).getSingleResult();
```

Hope it helps!